# Who has gotten WiringPi working in a ROS 2 C++ node? Want to control GPIO on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22

Tags: ros2, c++, ros-humble, raspberry-pi

What I've tried and works to know the WiringPi library is working on my Raspberry Pi 4.

- `g++` compiling a test `cpp` script using `WiringPi`.
- Terminal `gpio` commands (`gpio -g mode 18 output` sets pin 18 to be an output)
- Physically wiring an output to an input. Writing to the output changed the input correctly
- All results of changing `pinMode` and `digialWrite` were correct on the `gpio readall`

Properly linking the external WiringPi library into my ROS 2 package, `wiringPi.h` file in my `cpp` node, and using the same code as the test `cpp` script, it doesn't work. Is there something special I need to account for? Is there a ROS 2 background thread preventing WiringPi from functioning?

#### Code

```
class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    MyNode() : Node("my-node")
    {
        wiringPiSetupGpio();
        if (wiringPiSetupGpio() == -1)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize WiringPiSetup");
        }
        pinMode(18, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(17, INPUT);
        // Jumper wire connecting pin 18 to 17
        digitalWrite(18, HIGH);
        RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "%d", digitalRead(17);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    try
    {
        auto node = std::make_shared<MyNode>();
        RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Starting node");

        rclcpp::spin(node);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &ex)
    {
        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("main"), "Exception during node initialization: " << ex.what());
    }

    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

18 does not change to OUTPUT nor is it set to HIGH. 17 is by default an INPUT.

#### Reference

- GPIO terminal comamnds I was testing: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/c-wiringpi-setup
- Example I used in my `cpp` file: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/c-wiringpi-example

Comment: Post a minimal example of your ROS node and how you spin it in `main()`. Without that one can only guess...

Comment: Updated it with code snippet.

Comment: The only issue I see is that at the start of your question you state "sets pin 17 to be an output" while in the code you set 17 as the input. So maybe you are measuring on the wrong pin and it actually works?

Comment: No matter what I change, nothing reflects in `gpio readall`. That was just an example. Let me change it so it's not confusing.

Comment: Do you think it's something to do with how the ROS 2 spins the node?

Comment: No. Moreover, all your code is in the constructor, which finishes before the `spin` call. Could it be due to needed privileges? E.g. stand alone program run with root privileges, vs. ROS code without?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `wiringPiSetup()` inside `main` and before spinning the node (`rclcpp::spin(node)`). It should look like this.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    wiringPiSetupGpio();
    if (wiringPiSetupGpio() == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    auto node = std::make_shared<MyNode>();
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Starting node");

    rclcpp::spin(node);

    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Although putting `wiringPiSetup()` in the constructor doesn't throw any errors, it looks like you want the initialization to be separate from the rest of the ROS Node. I have no references for this solution.